# jquerymobile. Footer disappears when switching pages quickly

Tags: jquery-mobile, footer

I have just started using jquery mobile and got a weird thing happening. When I click the navigation bar quickly(on different item each time) my footer disappears on one of these pages.
Here is my code (that's the main file but all other files are identical with the exception of ui-active class on the nav bar item)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title in head</title>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/lib/jquery.mobile-1.0b1.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/jquery-1.6.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/jquery.mobile-1.0b1.js"></script>
        <script>
            $.mobile.defaultPageTransition='none';
            //$.mobile.useFastClick='false';
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" class="type-interior">
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="f" data-position="fixed">
                <h1>Friends</h1>
                <a href="../../" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext" data-direction="reverse" class="ui-btn-right jqm-home">Home</a>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                                    <p>
                        This is the test
                    </p>
                    <ul data-role="listview" data-dividertheme="d" style="margin-top: 0;">
                        <li data-role="list-divider">
                            A
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="index.html">Adam Kinkaid</a>
                        </li>
                        <li data-role="list-divider">
                            B
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="index.html">Bob Cabot</a>
                        </li>
                        <li data-role="list-divider">
                            C
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="index.html">Caleb Booth</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

            </div><!-- /content -->

            <div data-role="footer" data-id="footer" data-position="fixed">
                <h1>Footer</h1>

            </div><!-- /footer -->
                <div data-role="navbar">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/views/first.html" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">First</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/views/second.html">Second</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/views/third.html">Third</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- /navbar -->
        </div><!-- /page -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Should I just stop using jquerymobile footers or does anyone know a workaround?

Thank you!